# checking/verifying python code

Tags: python, scripting

Python is a relatively new language for me and I already see some of the trouble areas of maintaining a scripting language based project. I am just wondering how the larger community , with a scenario when one has to maintain a fairly large code base written by people who are not around anymore, deals with the following situations:

1. Return type of a function/method. Assuming past developers didn't document the code very well, this is turning out to be really annoying as I am basically reading code line by line to figure out what a method/function is suppose to return.
2. Code refactoring: I figured a lot of code need to be moved around, edited/deleted and etc. But lot of times simple errors, which would otherwise be compile time error in other compiled languages e.g. -  wrong number of arguments, wrong type of arguments, method not present and etc, only show up when you run the code and the code reaches the problematic area. Therefore, whether a re-factored code will work at all or not can only be known once you run the code thoroughly. I am using PyLint with PyDev but still I find it very lacking in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that's an issue with dynamically typed interpreted languages.

There are to important things that can help:

1. Good documentation
2. Extensive unit-testing.

They apply to other languages as well of course, but here they are *especially* important.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know If code is not documented at all and the author isn't around anymore it's up to you to find out what the ode actually does.

That's why people should always stick to certain guidelindes that can be enforced by stylecheckers like pep8. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8

Comments and docstrings should be included in every method to avoid such situation you're describing. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring

Also unittests are very helpfull for refactoring since you can check if you broke something with the click of a button. http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

hope this helps

Comment: PEP 8 adherence is certainly good, but it doesn't even touch on the issues OP ask about.

Comment: OP also asked about refactoring. In my oponion PEP8 does help with that. Since it enforces a consistent style it makes it easier to read code from other people. Of course it really is almost solely about style with PEP8 so it's not the cure of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already mentioned documentation and unit-testing as being the main tools here. I want to add a third: the Python shell. One of the huge advantages of a non-compiled language like Python is that you can easily fire up the shell, import your module, and run the code there to see what it does and what it returns.

Linked to this is the Python debugger: just put `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` at any point in your code, and when you run it you will be dropped into the interactive debugger where you can inspect the current values of the variables. In fact, the pdb shell is an actual Python shell as well, so you can even change things there.